# product of Hardy functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f,g$ two analytic functions defined on the complex disk, and $f,g \in H^2$ the Hardy space, that is, $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n)z^n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(n)|^2 < \infty$, and $g$ satisfies the same condition. How do I proof that $fg \in H^2$? (I have some problems to handle with the Cauchy product of power series).

Comment: I don't think this is true. Where did you find this statement?

Comment: A teacher told me to use this assertion to proof that $(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z})^{\alpha}$ is in the Hardy space $H^2$, when $0<\alpha<1/2$.

Comment: The hint does not seem helpful. I would rather use the property that $|\cot(t/2)|^{2\alpha}$ or $|\sin(t/2)|^{-2\alpha}$ is integrable for $0<\alpha<1/2$ and $|t|\le \pi.$ You can actually admit $|\alpha|<1/2.$

Answer (score -1):

Since $f,g \in H^2$ and $[-\pi,\pi]$ is a measurable subset, we are under the conditions of Hölder's inequality, then

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})g(re^{i\theta})|d\theta \leq \left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Besides, a function $f \in H^2$ if, and only if, $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{-}}\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$$ is bounded. Putting together this two assertions, it holds

$$ \lim_{r \to 1^- }\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})g(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta \leq \lim_{r \to 1^-}\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \left( \left( \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) $$

which is finite since $f,g \in H^2$.

Comment: The first line is wrong (holder's inequality is used wrong)

Comment: I would appreciate if you tell me why it is exactly wrong. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: holder goes $|\int fg| \le \|f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2}$. That's not what you wrote, which is $|\int fg| \le \sqrt{\|f\|_{L^1}} \sqrt{\|g\|_{L^1}}$

Comment: If $S$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Lebesgue measure and $f,g$ are measurable real or complex -valued functions on $S$, then, the Hölder inequality is $\int_S |f(x)g(x)|dx \leq (\int_S|f(x)|^pdx)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\int_S |g(x)|^qdx)^{\frac{1}{q}}$. Take $S = [-\pi,\pi]$ and $p=q=2$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my comment says, and not what your answer says. [I've marked a screenshot to make it more obvious.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX3Bc.png) And in the third line, the LHS has $\int |f^2g^2|$, which is different from the first line.

Comment: You're right, I did not see the exponent is missing, thank you very much!

Comment: Please consider the exponent on the LHS of the 3rd line now. It does not follow from the first line. If the earlier wrong inequality was correct, then your current third line would follow by putting $f^2$ instead of $f$ and $g^2$ instead of $g$.